# Why won't jQuery text() method work with 3.7, but will with 3.6.4?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on implementing some jQuery into a WordPress site. The site appears to have jQuery 3.7 loading, as I find this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sharpsync.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
```

However, I am trying to run this code and it will not work, unless I load jquery version 3.6.4 as well.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sharpsync.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0" id="jquery-core-js"></script>

<button>Set text content for all p elements</button>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("Hello world!");
  });
});
</script>
```

If I add

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then it works. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

That script loads jQuery in [no-conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode which removes the global `$()` function. Note the last line

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
```

The simplest solution is to swap the outer `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` for `jQuery(function($) { ... })` which adds the same *ready* event listener while also scoping `jQuery` as `$`.

```html
<script src="https://sharpsync.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.0"></script>

<button>Set text content for all p elements</button>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").text("Hello world!");
  });
});
</script>
```